# For Loops - certain situation I am struggling to find logic for

Tags: vb.net

I need to loop through a table and check if there are 4 rows with a specific column containing 1 - 4 values.

Example of table:

| **cty** | **st** | **val** |

| 03      |   23   |    1      |

| 03      |   23   |    2      |

| 03      |   23   |    3      |

| 03      |   23   |    4      |

I need to check to see if the column val contains the 1 - 4 values. The table will always be sorted by val ASC, but the table may not always contain all 4 values. If 1 - 4 is not present in this table I need to issue an error message to the user. (Not the problem).

My issue is the loop logic to check this.

I have tried a couple different ways and this is what I currently have that doesn't quite get what I'm looking for.

```
For i As Integer = 1 To 4 Step 1
    For Each dr As DataRow In dt.Rows

        'if not all 4 growing season per county are entered, show error message
        If i <> dr("grows") Then

            FillErrorResultObject("ERROR00139", "", "", strCountyName, "", "", "", "", "", dtErrorTable, objErrorResult)
            blnError = True
            Exit For

        End If

    Next
    If blnError = True Then Exit For
Next
```

****EDIT - 'val' in my example table is the same column as 'grows' in the code example.  Figured I'd leave it as is and just add this comment.

Comment: Wouldn't it just be `If dr("Grows") < 0 or dr("Grows") > 4 Then Error...`?  Get rid of the `i` loop.

Comment: I need to make sure grows has all the values of 1, 2, 3, 4.  This statement wouldn't error if I only had 1 and 2, or 1, 2, and 3, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you need to know if all four values are present in the table, you need to track the four values to see if they are present or not.  You can use a dictionary for this:

```
Dim d As New Dictionary(Of Integer, Boolean)
For i As Integer = 1 To 4
  d.Add(i, False)
Next

For Each dr As DataRow In dt.Rows
  Dim v As Integer = Convert.ToInt32(dr("Grows"))
  If d.ContainsKey(v) Then
    d(v) = True
  End If
Next

Dim showError As Boolean = False
For Each kvp As KeyValuePair(Of Integer, Boolean) In d
  If Not kvp.Value Then
    showError = True
  End If
Next
If showError Then
  MessageBox.Show("Error")
End If
```

Comment: Thank you. Exactly what I needed and works like a charm.  I've never used a dictionary before.